# Why is Redshift throwing error code 1218 for a string that is NOT null terminated?

Tags: amazon-redshift, null-terminated

I am querying the `STL_LOAD` table in redshift and I am seeing this error:

```
Invalid null byte - field longer than 1 byte
```

The error code is `1218`. According to their documentation:

```
When using NULL AS '\0', a field containing a null terminator (NUL, or UTF-8 0000) contained more than one byte.
```

The culprit data of the error looks like this: `\\u0000\\u0001\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u00ff`. But the string is not "null terminated", it actually ends with the small accented latin character `ÿ`. So why is the error being thrown?

I just need an explanation of what the error means, I cannot seem to find anything useful online
I am also using `NULL AS '\0'` setting for my COPY command

Comment: It seems you are trying to load non-ascii strings to Redshift

Comment: Yes, some strings are non-ascii